# Which mapper gets allocated

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to incorporate certain security functions in Hadoop mapreduce and I want to know this. For a mapreduce program, How can I know which mapper gets allocated. 
 
Suppose I am writing wordcount example and using 5 files and there is a cluster of machines. How can I know which file is accessed by which machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your mapper:

```
CombineFileSplit split = (CombineFileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
Path[] paths = split.getPaths();
for (Path path : paths) {
    //Source HDFS file path belongs to processing input split
}
```

But you should understand that when mapper starts it process not a file. In general terms mapper process input split which may consists of several source HDFS files. As a result a method I described above can return more then one input files.